# VW Golf R mk 8 - suddenly developed 7 faults

Tags: brakes, abs, electronic-stability-control

Hope you can help. Got in my car this morning, turned on the ignition and out of nowhere it showed SEVEN faults.

- Error: ParkPilot
- Error: start-stop system
- Error: ABS/stabilisation control (ESC)
- Auto hold is unavailable
- Front assist unavailable
- Brake servo restricted
- Please replace key battery

Can't get where this could have come from, though the car had a full service about 2-3 months ago. Everything was fine, although they did find and remove some blue plastic clips from the front suspension on both sides (I think).

Any ideas what this is all about? Some of them don't sound good at all, but I'm not much good with cars...

Thanks so much in advance!

Russell

Comment: Had the same thing on my mk8 Golf GTD.. they looked it’s all
Over and updated the software but couldn’t find any fault with it Everytime I turn the car off the Brake server is restricted come up on the screen and there’s a very distinctive grunting/vibration sound from just under the centre compartments.